# SQL select multiple coloumns each one count somthing

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have a problem when displaying several coloumns with counting,  this is my table "Empo" :

```
idEmp    DeptA   DeptB  
----    ----    ----    
1       23      7      
2       42      23
3       23      11
4       23      17
```

And I want to count number of idEmp , and the number of times where '23' is in every Dept to get something like this:

```
count(id) count(DeptA)   count(DeptB)  
----      ----           ----    
4         3              1
```

also i have another table "Rapport"

```
idRap   DeptA   bonnus 
----    ----    ----    
1       23      200      
2       42      23
3       23      346
4       77      44
```

and i want to get also the sum of the bonnus for the DeptA

How do I do this in MySQL?

thank you

Comment: do you want a sum of the bonnus for DeptA or do you want a sum of bonnus for DeptA filtered by 23 ?

Comment: a sum of bonnus for DeptA filtered by 23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method I have used in the past is to use a combination of Count and Sum.

```
select count(idEmp), 
sum(Case when DeptA = 23 Then 1 else 0 End), 
sum(Case when DeptB = 23 Then 1 else 0 End)
from tableX
```

Edit for question.
I would use a subselect for the new case to prevent duplicates being added to the original counts. see below.

```
select count(idEmp) as RecordCount, 
sum(Case when DeptA = 23 Then 1 else 0 End) as DeptA23Count, 
(select sum(bonnus) from Rapport where DeptA = 23) as BonnusForDeptA23,
sum(Case when DeptB = 23 Then 1 else 0 End) as DeptB23Count,
from tableX
```

Or something like that depending on where criteria.

Comment: @AymenYasser see modified answer

Comment: thank you i did thought of subselect , 
but i didn't think is good for performance 
is it ?

Comment: @AymenYasser The use of a sub select in this case is justified if not required to avoid using distinct - performance is dependent on the size of the table - this shouldn't be a problem as it appears to be relatively lightweight, it can be improved if you were to add indexes on the DeptA column. Without more information it is extremely hard to advise.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
SELECT COUNT(idEmp) AS id,
  SUM(IF(DeptA = 23,1,0)) as COUNT_DeptA,
  SUM(IF(DeptB = 23,1,0)) as COUNT_Deptb
FROM youtTable;
```

Comment: Ups my iPhone . I habe Chance my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try below query :-

```
select (select count(id) from test) as countID,
(select count(DeptA) from test where DeptA=23) as CountDeptA,
(select count(DeptB) from test where DeptB=23) as CountDeptB
```